# fire onClick function from child component

Tags: reactjs

> TLDR: How would i retrieve the console.log from the child component
>   after url has been submitted

I want to be able to get the response data from the child component after a url has been submitted. How would i be able to do this ?

In other words how i be able to fire the `onClick` function after a url has been submitted ?

code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-feather-fjkv6

**Parent**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Child from './Child';
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url:'',
      outputUrl:''
    }
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      url: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.url)
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.url} placeholder="Enter url " />
              <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
          </form>
        {/* if have url else enter test url */}

          <Child url={this.state.url} method={'GET'} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

How would i retrieve the console.log from the child component after url has been submitted ? I'm slightly confused. Sorry if this is looks confusing.

**Child**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Child extends Component {    
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data:[]
    }
  }
  // componentDidUpdate or try this
  onClick(){
     const url = `${this.props.url}`;  
     if(this.props.method === "GET"){
        axios.get(url).then( res => {
          this.setState({
            data: res.data
          })
          console.log(this.state.data)
        })
     }

     else if(this.props.method === "POST"){
        axios.get(url).then( res => {
          this.setState({
            data: res.data
          })
          console.log(this.state.data)
        })
     }

  } 
  render(){
    return (
      null
    );

  }

}

export default Child;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Also, please provide a jsFiddle.

Comment: fire the console.log from onClick after a url has been submitted, this was my attempt too.

Comment: If your aim is to log the entered url once the user submits the form, It should work even without the Child component.

Comment: im sorry get the response data, i have sandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-feather-fjkv6

Comment: i want to be able to get the response data, from the entered url

Comment: not the url. hopefully this make sense now.

Comment: Please check if this helps. https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cloud-kwcbu

Comment: getting an error, `The above error occurred in the <div> component:`

Comment: This is getting the reponse data from the parent component, which is not what im looking for. I want to pass url and from the child component console.log(reponse.data)

Comment: Would that be possible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195707/discussion-between-sreeram-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please! see render method on Child Component

```
class Child extends Component {
  static onClick() {
    // do something
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  // componentDidUpdate or try this
  onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = `${this.props.url}`;
    if (this.props.method === "GET") {
      axios.get(url).then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.data
        });
        console.log(this.state.data);
      });
    } else if (this.props.method === "POST") {
      axios.get(url).then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.data
        });
        console.log(this.state.data);
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.onClick}>Click Me</div>;// <------
  }
}
```